# PHP if...else statement confusion

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, if-statement, custom-fields

This is my first project digging into PHP and mySQL databases, and it's been a steep learning curve so far.  I'm near the end of a Wordpress project and could use some help on if...else statements, which have been stumping me for a while.  It uses custom fields.

Essentially I need the below flow, where "c01-sp-a" is a one word text variable and "c01-sp-v" is a number.  I put variables in [] to clarify:

```
if ([c01-sp-a] = null)
    [text of c01-sp-v]
else
    <a href="http://www.example.com/[text of c01-sp-a]" title="[text of c01-sp-a]" target="_blank">[text of c01-sp-v]</a>
```

I'd have to repeat this a few times, but I'd imagine having a good example for me would get me going.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to echo something or what, it's not clarified what's the expected and what's the unusual result

Comment: You need to add curly braces where appropriate

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this?

```
if ($c01_sp_a == null) {
    echo $c01_sp_v;
} else {
    echo '<a href="http://www.example.com/'.$c01_sp_a'." title="'.$c01_sp_a.'" target="_blank">'.$c01_sp_v'.</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your variable can not contain '-' , you have to change your variable names ( i assume that variables are c01_sp_a and $c01_sp_v

```
if ($c01_sp_a == null)
    echo $c01_sp_a;
else
    <a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $c01_sp_a;?>" title="<?php echo $c01_sp_a; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $c01_sp_v;?></a>
```